# How to do padding on a textarea (titanium)

Tags: titanium-alloy

This works fine with a text field:

```
<TextField id="txtNick" paddingLeft='15' top='10' maxLength='20' width = '300' />
```

However the following code does not work in a text area:

```
<TextArea id="txtAbout" maxLength='250' paddingRight='10' top='10' width = '300' borderStyle="Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED"/>
```

Any idea how to achieve padding? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with single TextArea. but you can:

`<View height="Ti.UI.SIZE">
<TextArea left="10 right="10" />
</View>`

Comment: Does that make a full screen view and shifts the text area to the right?

Comment: Yes, it's an hack, but you don't have alternatives.